# Deploying SSL certificate with private Root/Intermediate CA - trust chain not shown completly

Tags: nginx, configuration, ssl-certificate

I am trying to deploy on my nginx instance a SSL certificate signed by own Intermediate CA, itself signed by own Root CA.

I have followed very carefully this [very good OpenSSL guide](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/index.html) to create my 3 certificates: the Root CA, the Intermediate CA and my leaf certificate.

When I connect with openssl to my running nginx instance I get:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = FR, ST = France, L = Paris, O = Maugeri & Co, OU = Maugeri & Co Certificate Authority, CN = Maugeri & Co Root CA
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=FR/ST=France/L=Paris/O=Maugeri & Co/OU=Maugeri & Co Web Services/CN=www.example.com
   i:/C=FR/ST=France/O=Maugeri & Co/OU=Maugeri & Co Certificate Authority/CN=Maugeri & Co Intermediate CA
 1 s:/C=FR/ST=France/O=Maugeri & Co/OU=Maugeri & Co Certificate Authority/CN=Maugeri & Co Intermediate CA
   i:/C=FR/ST=France/L=Paris/O=Maugeri & Co/OU=Maugeri & Co Certificate Authority/CN=Maugeri & Co Root CA
 2 s:/C=FR/ST=France/L=Paris/O=Maugeri & Co/OU=Maugeri & Co Certificate Authority/CN=Maugeri & Co Root CA
   i:/C=FR/ST=France/L=Paris/O=Maugeri & Co/OU=Maugeri & Co Certificate Authority/CN=Maugeri & Co Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=FR/ST=France/L=Paris/O=Maugeri & Co/OU=Maugeri & Co Web Services/CN=www.example.com
issuer=/C=FR/ST=France/O=Maugeri & Co/OU=Maugeri & Co Certificate Authority/CN=Maugeri & Co Intermediate CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5286 bytes and written 421 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 282F0F1A393322D5EC760D85B61A3D5316EF7ECA4C22E9EF9CC05FFE82D73259
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: E562CE13B5398E869F7493D1B731506F3B178DAF8AE0142A11A34CD1C88A15496C2BE608129469510EBE083038A8556C
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - d2 df 91 71 0e b8 a1 df-c4 3f e4 eb fc d9 fa 26   ...q.....?.....&
    0010 - 7d 0e 2f c4 93 22 6d 64-19 f0 ba 3e 98 9f 60 4d   }./.."md...>..`M
    0020 - fe f6 2a 4b dc 39 bc 31-7f 35 d6 da 93 e6 b5 5e   ..*K.9.1.5.....^
    0030 - f2 19 26 04 62 44 d4 73-9b 95 a8 6e 2e 72 86 94   ..&.bD.s...n.r..
    0040 - 7b 5b 8a bc ac ee 09 71-e8 ec c4 96 e3 89 20 f2   {[.....q...... .
    0050 - c2 3b 64 c2 bd 03 a2 cb-a1 2e 66 4f 5b 7d f1 0a   .;d.......fO[}..
    0060 - 19 05 e1 3a 32 22 e9 03-a6 46 a0 6e d6 0b f1 b9   ...:2"...F.n....
    0070 - 52 b6 88 88 98 dd 18 a2-37 37 15 7d 86 39 b5 16   R.......77.}.9..
    0080 - 35 e9 87 55 3e 23 c2 19-c3 b8 84 de de 10 e3 5b   5..U>#.........[
    0090 - 4e eb 68 a2 55 ff f6 88-f4 1b b9 d9 fa c0 77 ad   N.h.U.........w.
    00a0 - 58 49 ce a6 59 08 4f 22-64 2f 1f 7d a2 2f 48 06   XI..Y.O"d/.}./H.

    Start Time: 1503749297
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
---
```

This is encouraging because I see that the section **Certificate chain** contains the 3 certificates.

However there is only one PEM presented and these messages do confirm there is something wrong in how the trust chain is presented:

- "verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain"
- "No client certificate CA names sent"

My nginx configuration is:

```
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name www.example.com;

        root html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /root/ca/intermediate/certs/ca-intermediate-cert-chain.cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /root/ca/intermediate/private/www.example.com.key.pem;
        [...]
        }
}
```

The file ca-intermediate-cert-chain.cert.pem contains the 3 PEMs in this order (which should be good since nginx starts without error):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[Root CA certificate PEM]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[Intermediate CA certificate PEM]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[Leaf certificate PEM]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Locally I can verify successfully my leaf certificate against the CA:

```
# openssl verify -CAfile intermediate/certs/ca-intermediate-cert-chain.cert.pem     intermediate/certs/www.example.com.cert.pem
intermediate/certs/www.example.com.cert.pem: OK
```

Do you have any idea on what is wrong in my configuration?

Thanks in advance!

**My configuration:**

- nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
- OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

Comment: I don't see a issue here? "No client certificate CA names sent" is because we re not sending any certificate to the server. If I do `openssl s_client -connect www.github.com:443` or any other site I will get the same thing. Next you are getting `verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain`, which is valid because you have not trusted to your self-signed CA on your machine. So again nothing wrong with it as well

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It makes me think I haven't been clear enough in the description of my problem. Actually, my problem here is that I would like that the whole trust chain is being transmitted and I the section "Server certificate" I see only one PEM sent (the one of my leaf cert). I would like my nginx to send the pem of the leaf cert, the intermediate and the Root CA. The same content as my file ca-intermediate-cert-chain.cert.pem. Is this possible?

Comment: ... I would like to get the same result as in:
"openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -showcerts"
where you can see that the 3 certificates PEM are shown.

Comment: So what is the output of `openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -showcerts` ?

Comment: I have updated this output above. As you can observe there is only one BEGIN CERTIFICATE / END CERTIFICATE block listed. While, with Google case, one can sees all certificates of the chain.

Comment: Ooooh !! I forgot to append the "-showcerts" to my openssl command !! Now I can see indeed what I expected to see (the 3 BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE block). I apologise Tarun for this stupid mistake ... Thank you very much for taking time to review this case with me!

Comment: No worries, happens at times